# $\zeta'(s)\ll (\log t)^2$ using Cauchy's formula, proof verification

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory, cauchy-integral-formula

> For $s=\sigma+it$,  $t\geq 8$, $1-\frac{1}{2}(\log t)^{-1}\leq \sigma\leq 2$,
> \begin{equation}
> \zeta(s)\ll \log t \text{ and } \zeta'(s)\ll (\log t)^2
> \end{equation}

The first part can easily been proved, even for $1-\log(t)^{-1}\leq \sigma\leq 3$, but I am not quite sure about the second part. The authos claims that the estimation for $\zeta'$ immediately follows from the Cauchy formula
\begin{equation}
\zeta'(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\vert z-s\vert=r} \frac{\zeta(z)}{(z-s)^2}\mathrm{dz}
\end{equation}
with $r=\frac{1}{2}(\log t)^{-1}$.
And it took my quite long to figure out why, but I am not sure if my proof is correct: I start with

\begin{align*}
\zeta'(s)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\vert z-s\vert=r} \frac{\zeta(z)}{(z-s)^2}\mathrm{dz}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\zeta(s+re^{i\varphi})}{(s+re^{i\varphi}-s)^2}ire^{i\varphi}\mathrm{d\varphi}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\zeta(s+re^{i\varphi})\frac{i}{r}e^{-i\varphi}\mathrm{d\varphi}
\end{align*}

From this point I see that $1-\frac{1}{\log t}\leq\mathrm{Re}(s+\frac{e^{i\varphi}}{2\log t})\leq 3$, so we can apply our first estimation for $\zeta(s)$ that gives us (we also get rid of constants)
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\zeta(s+re^{i\varphi})\frac{i}{r}e^{-i\varphi}\mathrm{d\varphi}\\
&\ll \log t\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg\vert \frac{1}{(2\log t)^{-1}}e^{-i\varphi}\bigg\vert\mathrm{d\varphi}\\
&=(\log t)^2\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg\vert e^{-i\varphi}\bigg\vert\mathrm{d\varphi} = (\log t)^2
\end{align*}

I don't know how to describe it but this proof feels kinda weird. Can anyone review this proof if it is legit to argue like I do? Am I missing any requirements about the asymptotic behavier?

Comment: This is a legit proof. You may find out more similar treatments in Titchmarsh's _The Theory of the Riemann's Zeta-Function_.